# Kivy metric unit for actual (not idealized) pixels?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to draw scale-independent lines in Kivy that are fixed n-pixel width, while exploiting the Scale (and Translate) instructions to zoom into parts of a graph, etc. while leaving the line-widths alone.

I thought that dp(n) would be my friend, see [Kivy Metrics](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/metrics.html). It worked on an external 1080p monitor: lines stay the same width, while the scale affects the vertex locations of the graph. However on the Retina screen of a MacBook Pro the dp(1) lines are very thick... and Kivy doesn't allow me to use dashes.

If you look in the Kivy code at [Kivy Metrics module (line 207)](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/metrics.py), you see this suspicious reference to Mac OS, and a suspicious "EventLoop.window.dpi / 96" for the density setting. I bet Retinas have some gynormous DPI.

Is there a way of doing what I want in Kivy: having a fixed pixel-width that stays the same width even under scaling?